# bootstrap modal crashing when setting value

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, web

In my website I'm trying to use bootstrap modal to ask for two values and get the middle of it. I have a button that when clicked, calculates the middle of the two values and sets a value I have declared in the modal-body code. It sets the value and then the modal disappears and the webpage reloads. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

In the HTML, modal-body:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Get Middle.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on">$</span>
            <input class="span2" id="lowSide" type="text">
        </div>
        to 
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on">$</span>
            <input class="span2" id="highSide" type="text">
        </div> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn" onClick="enteredRange(lowSide.value,highSide.value)">Enter</button>
        </form>
    <form class="form-inline"> <label>middle:</label> <input id="middle" type="text" /> </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript function to set it:

```
function enteredRange(x,y)
{
    var low=parseFloat(x);
    var high=parseFloat(y);
    var middle1=parseInt((low+high)/2);

    middle.value=middle1;
}
```

I've also done

```
document.getElementById('middle').value=middle1;
```

in place of the middle.value=middle1 and gotten the same result.

Any idea on how I could set this up correctly?

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know how to, I can put the entire modal code if that helps

Comment: Is this form in the modal markup?

Comment: I added all of the modal HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the **`<form></form>`** elements, since you don't need them and they cause the page to redirect via form-post. I also removed some unnecessary closing divs. I don't know if rest of your code requires them. And finally cleaned your markup a bit.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
         <h3 id="myModalLabel">Get Middle.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on">$</span>
                <input class="span2" id="lowSide" type="text" />
            </div>
            to
            <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on">$</span>
                <input class="span2" id="highSide" type="text" />
            </div>
            <button class="btn" onClick="enteredRange(lowSide.value,highSide.value)">Enter</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-inline">
            <label>middle:</label>
            <input id="middle" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="btn">OPEN MODAL</button>
```

Here is the **[working code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/rbpxR/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are happening here.

1. When clicking the submit button, the form is actually being submitted.
2. If no `method` is specified for a `form` it defaults to `GET`.

That's why you see the error.

You need to prevent the form submit. You could simply use `onsubmit` to do this:

```
<form class="form-inline" onsubmit="return false;">
```

---

I'm not advocating in-line JavaScript so here's a slighter nicer way; add an ID to the form and attach a click handler which prevents submit:

#### HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="middle-calculator">
```

#### JS:

```
document.getElementById('middle-calculator').addEventListener('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
},false);
```

`e` here is for "event".

[The working example (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jkUtu/1/)

---

One other small thing... be careful when copying from the Bootstrap documentation. Always use HTML entities for special characters; the close modal icon should be `&times;` (or `&#215;`).

Comment: You're welcome :). Just for your information, removing the `<form>` leaves the markup invalid technically since `<inputs>` need lie inside one (a `<form>`).